# Blender (3.6.2) Asset Library does not think that the asset browser is set to the current file library

Tags: asset-browser

I'm not really sure how to approach this. I've found zero results online for this specific error. I have repeatedly made sure that my asset library is set to the same directory as the blend I'm working in (visible in screenshot) and I have also tested in other directories (to no avail) which wouldn't be a good option anyways due to all the file paths that would break and have to be manually re-entered.

Here's a composited screenshot showing the error, the file directory at the top of my blender instance, and the asset browser directory in user preferences. The name of the blend is censored, but I've not censored any important directory information.

[image: screencap]